# Create a new column which need to handle sum of existing column value in a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following columns in a table:

Product Name
Quantity

I want to add the quantities of the product if the name of the product is same. For example if I have product with the same name twice, I want the total quantities of the products to be added and get a result.

This is the table and I want to add the quantities of the same item:

**current data in table**

```
Name            Quantity
Pen              3 
Pencil           2
Pen              6
Eraser           7
Eraser           6
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Name                   Quantity         New Column
Pen                        3               3
Pen                        6               9 
Pencil                     2               2
Eraser                     7               7
Eraser                     6              13
```

Comment: I don't understand your output. You want a running total or count grouped by name?  If you group by name, then you would get example, "Pen 9"

Comment: I want running total. Suppose a new row is added as Pen 4 then output for this row should be Pen     4      13

Comment: -1 for not demonstrating any research effort

Comment: hi Vignesh, Thanks for the reply. Trying it in w3schools on products table not able to run it properly there. Need to tryit on monday only.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Thank u it worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to use [**ROWNUM**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) And **`Sum`** With **`Partition`**

May be something like this

```
SELECT Name,
       Quantity,
       SUM(Quantity) Over (Partition By Name Order By ROWNUM) As Sum_Value
From Table1
Order By Name Desc;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bccc/7)**

---

*Output:*

```
NAME    QUANTITY    SUM_VALUE
-----------------------------
Pencil  2           2
Pen     3           3
Pen     6           9
Eraser  7           7
Eraser  6           13
```

Comment: Or without ROWNUM: 
       SUM(Quantity) Over (Partition By Name Order By Name rows unbounded preceding) As Sum_Value

Answer (score 0):

You can add insert, update and delete triggers that handles the update of this new column. Example (untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER X
   BEFORE INSERT ON T
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.total_quantity := ( select sum(Quantity) from T
                                where name = :new.name ) + :new.quantity
END;
/
```

To populate the existing rows use Vignesh solution

Comment: Every new row will get a value corresponding to the sum of the previous. Note that this only happens when a new row is inserted. Triggers for delete and update of name has to be implemented to. This is sometimes referred to as an incremental evaluation system (IES). As mentioned you will have to populate existing rows using something similar as Vignesh.

Comment: It might be more efficient to: ` set new.total_quantity := ( select coalesce(max(total_Quantity),0) from T                                 where name = :new.name ) + :new.quantity`